# Proving a function isn't homotopic to a map to the boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $S$ a finite dimensional, convex, Hausdorff space.  Moreover, let $f:X \to S$ be a closed, surjective map with $\tilde{H}^q(f^{-1}(s))=0$ for all $q\ge 0$ and $s\in S$, where $\tilde{H}$ denotes reduced Čech-cohomology with coefficients in a module $G$.  Finally, let $\partial X = f^{-1}(\partial S)$.

I am trying to show:

> If $f:(X,\partial X) \to (S,\partial S)$ induces a non-zero homomorphism $f^*:\tilde{H}(S,\partial S) \to \tilde{H}(X,\partial X)$ then $f$ is not homotopic to any map $\bar{f}: X \to \partial S$ (that agrees with $f$ on $\partial X$).

I'm not sure how to proceed.  My attempt thus far has basically been to observe that if $f$ is injective on $\partial X$, then if such a map $\bar{f}$ existed, $f^{-1} \circ \bar{f}: X \to \partial X$ would be a retract, hence it would follow that:

$$\tilde{H}^n(X) \approx \tilde{H}^n(\partial X) \oplus \tilde{H}^n(X,\partial X)$$

which can yield a contradiction with a step or two of extra work.  But clearly this isn't general.  I suspect that I need to show that such a map $\bar{f}$ induces the zero homomorphism by showing it's homotopic to a constant map, but I'm not sure how to.  Many thanks for any help!

(For those interested, this question is motivated by problem I.4.17.a on pages 54-55 in [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AuYlBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) book)

Comment: Can't you argue by homotopy invariance? If $\bar f$ would exist, then $f^\star=\bar f^\star$. The latter, however is zero. In fact, $\bar f^\star$ is already zero on relative Cech cochains since $\bar f$ maps $X$ into $\partial S$.

Comment: @JohannesHuisman I think this is exactly how I'd need to argue.  I'm just not clear why $\bar{f}^*=0$.   Could you briefly elaborate?

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I get it! Thank you very much, that makes complete sense.